# How to specify Firefox command line options using Selenium WebDriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I need to pass `--no-remote` to the Firefox started through Selenium in Python.  Is there a way to specify command line arguments?

Answer (score 4):

You can provide arguments using `FirefoxBinary.add_command_line_options()`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/path/to/firefox')
binary.add_command_line_options('--no-remote')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```